# WebExtensions: browser.webRequest.onCompleted never fires

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools, chrome-webrequest

I'm using the [Firefox WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) with the following [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts)

```
var log = console.log.bind(console)

log('hello world from browser extension')

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onCompleted
var filter = { urls: '<all_urls>' }
var extraInfoSpec = ['tlsInfo', 'responseHeaders']

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
    log(`Woo got a request, here's the details!`, details)
}, filter, extraInfoSpec) 

log('Added listener')
```

After loading the script from `about:debugging`, I see the following output in DevTools:

> hello world from browser extension

I do not see any output- there is no data from `browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener` and there is no 'Added listener' message.

**How do I make `browser.webRequest.onCompleted` work?**

For completeness, my `manifest.json` is below:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test extension.",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [webRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) API is only available to [background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts). You seem to using it inside a content script.

1. `urls` in `var filter = { urls: '<all_urls>' }` needs to be be an array `['<all_urls>']`.
2. `'tlsInfo'` in extraInfoSpec doesn't exist, I don't know where it comes from.
3. You need to specify an additional `<all_urls>` permission in your manifest.

**script.js**

```
var filter = { urls: ['<all_urls>'] }
var extraInfoSpec = ['responseHeaders']

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(`Woo got a request, here's the details!`, details)
}, filter, extraInfoSpec) 

console.log('Added listener')
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test extension.",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["script.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. 1 and 3 needed fixing, 2 is from the EFF tlsInfo proposal (but it turns out Mozilla is using a different implementation instead https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/d0a41d2e7770fc00df7844d5f840067cc35ba26f/toolkit/components/extensions/schemas/web_request.json#372)